# height propertyworking weirdly. css

Tags: jquery, html, css

The problem I seem to be having in more detail is where I have div element which some buttons and I need one button to take up the space above it but every time I change its height and position it correctly it moves the buttons next to it go down some.

---

```
#Cal_Border {
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
display:inline-block;
padding:2px;
}

#Num_View {
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
width:98.4%;
}

.Button {
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
width:22.9%;
height:10%;
padding-top:2px;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-bottom:2px;
}

#Equals {
height:40px;
position:relative;
top:-20px;
}

#Cal_Border input:focus {
outline:none;
}
```

---

```
<div id="Cal_Border">
        <input type="text" id="Num_View" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="<--" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="C" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="-/+" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="/" class="Button" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="1" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="2" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="3" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="x" class="Button" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="4" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="5" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="6" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="-" class="Button" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="7" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="8" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="9" class="Button" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="0" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="." class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="+" class="Button" />
        <input type="button" value="=" class="Button" id="Equals" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your indentation needs work ...

Comment: @AlienArrays: Fine, then `s/needs work/is quite unorthodox/`.  (Also, for the avoidance of doubt, note that I was referring to the OP's indentation and not yours.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it pretty close to how you want. Check the fiddle and let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru3QA/2/

```
#Cal_Border {
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
display:inline-block;
padding:2px 0 0 2px;
}

#Num_View {
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
width:96%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.Button {
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
width:22%;
height:10%;
padding-top:2px;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-bottom:2px;
}

#Equals {
height:40px;
position: relative;
top:-20px;
    float: right;
    left: -5px;
}

#Cal_Border input:focus {
outline:none;
}
```

---

OPTION 2 , probably better

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru3QA/3/

I just gave #Cal_border { position: relative; }

and made changes to that equals

```
#Equals {
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: @CDW I think I got it even better. Take a look at the edit. Option 2.

Comment: I actually have another question regarding this. How would I make it to where no matter what the window size is it will look like that no matter what.

Comment: @CDW It shows the same on all screen sizes with that option 2 fiddle I posted. Or do you mean you want the buttons and the calculator to be bigger on larger screens? If so, you'd have to use %'s in almost all places instead of pixel's. So you'd have to try adjusting with %'s, and if you can't get it , then post a  new question.